# After Fedora upgrade, system won't boot; what step to take next?

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub

I have a home server running Fedora 12 and decided to upgrade to Fedora 14.  I ran through the upgrade process using preupgrade with instructions from [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_use_PreUpgrad). I ran into an issue withi insufficient space n my /boot partition and followed the instructions from the troubleshooting section that allows the upgrade to download img files during the upgrade.  The last I saw my machine, it was happily downloading the img file.

When I cam back a few hours later, I have a system that will no longer boot.  I'm not a complete n00b, so I downloaded and booted from sysrescueCD.

It appears the /boot partition is still in place, and still has the Fedora 12 kernels; the grub menu.lst appears coherent (I've not looked at one before as I've used Slackware & lilo mostly).

Seems like trying to reload the MBR might make sense, but I'm at a loss as to how to troubleshoot and procede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it this way.  I downloaded for Fedora 14 install media.  I ran through the installation and told it to upgrade the existing install.  I had it reconfigure the boot loader during install.  All appears well

Answer (score 0):

Format the drive and re-install Fedora. That's what I would do.
Re-sizing/creating or deleting partitions will prevent future problems.

Comment: I have a fair amount of configuration in this installation that I'd rather not lose as yet.  My data is safe, but not the config info

Comment: @uSlackr Ok then make the previous OS functional since you got the files. Then try to upgrade again. Using a live CD you can reload the MBR.

Comment: exactly - its the how that eludes me...